# How do I edit the HTML output of Webmin?

Tags: ubuntu

As asked in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185736/what-is-wrong-with-this-frameset-code), Webmin keeps returning a blank page, due to some errors with the frameset code.

I know what I need to do to fix it... but I have no idea where the HTML is stored or generated, if it's even possible to change it that is. I've tried searching across the server for certain strings but no luck yet.

It's a Ubuntu server, with Webmin installed from the official deb package.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that restarting Webmin fixed the problem. Maybe got a little corrupted during an update...

This is the command to run:

```
/etc/webmin/restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure which repo you used to get webmin as it is not in any of the supported repos, but you can run this command to find where a package's files are installed.

```
dpkg -L package_name
```

Comment: My mistake, I installed it using the debian package from the website. Thanks for the help - from the look of it the HTML code might be inside binary files...